# Update Column from Recursive CTE (MySQL/MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cte, recursive, mariadb-10.5

I need to update the same table I'm using to create a recursive cte. The cte works as a select statement, but I can't get it to actually insert those values back into the table.

My code is below- basically I want to:

```
UPDATE tbl_1min
SET tbl_1min.ema9 = x.NewEma
WHERE x.id = tbl_1min.id
```

Can anyone help? I'd really appreciate it!

```
SET @NDays := 9;

WITH RECURSIVE anchor AS
    (
        SELECT
            a1.id,
            a1.close,
            a1.ema9
        FROM
            tbl_1min a1
),
x AS
    (
        SELECT
            anchor.id,
            anchor.close,
            x2.ema9 AS PrevEma,
            anchor.ema9,
            anchor.ema9 AS NewEma
        FROM
            anchor
        INNER JOIN
            anchor x2
        ON
            anchor.id - 1 = x2.id
        WHERE anchor.id = @NDays -- FIRST SEED ROW
UNION
   SELECT
    anchor.id,
    anchor.close,
    x.PrevEma,
    anchor.ema9,
    (((2 / (1 + @NDays)) * (anchor.close - x.PrevEma)) + x.PrevEma) AS NewEma
    FROM
        x
    JOIN anchor
    ON anchor.id = x.id + 1   -- `X` WALKS ITSELF
    )
SELECT
    id,
    NewEma
FROM 
    x
ORDER BY x.id
;
```

Comment: can you please provide a [mre] with all tables involved

Comment: @nbk yes, I'll work on an example- but might have to do it in excel, or manually calculate some rows. Will update shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I changed the recursive CTE to have both the anchor and child in the same CTE as that is standard. With that, I was able to show how the original table gets updated.

The answer consists of 3 parts as it pertains to the query:

1. A query to show the original contents of the table
2. The update based on the recursive CTE
3. A query of the original table showing the update - in this case, the 2 rows.

Update based on your other questions

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_1min(id int, close1 int,ema9 double);
INSERT INTO tbl_1min VALUES 
(1,1,10),
(2,1,15),
(3,1,25),
(4,1,30),
(5,1,35),
(6,1,40),
(7,1,45),
(8,1,50),
(9,1,55),
(10,1,60),
(11,1,65);

select * from tbl_1min;

SET @NDays := 9;
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT a.id, a.close1, a.ema9 AS PrevEma, a.ema9, a.ema9 AS NewEma
  FROM tbl_1min a
  WHERE a.id = @NDays -- FIRST SEED ROW
  UNION ALL
  SELECT y.id, y.close1, x.NewEma AS PrevEma, y.ema9,
  ((2 / (1 + @NDays) * (y.close1 - x.NewEma)) + x.NewEma) AS NewEma
  FROM cte x JOIN tbl_1min y ON y.id = x.id + 1   -- `X` WALKS ITSELF
)
```

Understand the result of the CTE by putting the below line right after the CTE and run - look at #s 10 and 11.

```
select * from cte order by id
```

Once you have reviewed the results of the CTE, remove the select statement for the CTE, run again and replace with the update and the select to see the data post-update.

```
UPDATE tbl_1min, cte SET tbl_1min.ema9 = cte.NewEma
WHERE cte.id = tbl_1min.id;

select * from tbl_1min;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any query typo with the created (with statements

The update can be de by joining the original with the cnstructed

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tbl_1min(id int, close int,ema9 varchar(30))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_1min VALUES (1,1,'test')
> ```

> ```
> SET @NDays := 9;
> WITH RECURSIVE anchor AS
>     (
>         SELECT
>             a1.id,
>             a1.close,
>             a1.ema9
>         FROM
>             tbl_1min a1
> ),
> x AS
>     (
>         SELECT
>             anchor.id,
>             anchor.close,
>             x2.ema9 AS PrevEma,
>             anchor.ema9,
>             anchor.ema9 AS NewEma
>         FROM
>             anchor
>         INNER JOIN
>             anchor x2
>         ON
>             anchor.id - 1 = x2.id
>         WHERE anchor.id = @NDays -- FIRST SEED ROW
> UNION
>    SELECT
>     anchor.id,
>     anchor.close,
>     x.PrevEma,
>     anchor.ema9,
>     (((2 / (1 + @NDays)) * (anchor.close - x.PrevEma)) + x.PrevEma) AS NewEma
>     FROM
>         x
>     JOIN anchor
>     ON anchor.id = x.id + 1   -- `X` WALKS ITSELF
>     )
> UPDATE tbl_1min t1
>         INNER JOIN
>     x ON t1.id = x.id 
> SET t1.ema9 = x.NewEma;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_1min
> ```
>
> ```
> id | close | ema9
> -: | ----: | :---
>  1 |     1 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a77e2ec69867245bbf4d8f4fa921e474)*

Comment: In fiddle it appears to run fine using compare. However, in my version of MariaDB 10.5, using HeidiSQL 11.1.0.6116 it gives:
SQL ERROR (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_1min t1
        INNER JOIN
    x ON t1.id = x.id 
SET t1.ema9...' at line 37

Comment: nmake the examle data with a exact copy from you system, there is no problem as far as i can see